# How to parse JSON and pass Value to another activity?

Tags: android, json, jsonobjectrequest

I am new to Android, so the name of the question might not be correct. Basically, I get a price as a JSONObject response (this is happening in fragment).

```
   public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            int price = response.getInt("price");

        } catch (JSONException ex) {

        }
    }
```

Now, how can I **pass the value of the price** to another activity and set it as setText in a TextView in that particular activity?

Answer (score 1):

Use this way.

**From Current Activity**

```
  public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            int price = response.getInt("price");
            Intent mIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, TargetActivity.class);
            mIntent.putExtra("price", price);
            startActivity(mIntent);
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
    }
```

**From Target Activity's onCreate**

```
   TextView txtPrice = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtPrice);
   txtPrice.setText(getIntent().getIntExtra("price"));
```

Comment: @jlively if this answer is helpful to you then mark as accepted answer so it help other.